# Visual studio 2013 locking PDB files when debugger is attached

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm working on a project that retrieves a number of Solutions from a team foundation server, to a temporary folder, uses Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.Build to build a release version for these Solutions, and cleans up the temporary folder with source code afterwards.

The problem arises when running my project with a debugger attached: 
during the clean-up I get a system.UnauthorizedAccessException with message

> "Access to the path ...\obj\release\CalithaLibrary.pdb denied".

Using sysinternals Process Explorer I found out that the lock was aquired by devenv.exe.

When I build a release version of my project and run it outside of visual studio the problem does not arise.

Any ideas as to why Visual Studio would aquire a lock of a PDB belonging to a project that was never opened by Visual Studio?

Edit: The first answer I received made me think I probably wasn't clear enough about the situation:

I'm debugging a project named "AutoReleaseService.exe" which uses Microsoft.Build.Execution.Buildmanager to build (but not run or debug!) a number of other projects, among which CalithaLibrary.

If I were trying to delete the AutoReleaseService.pdb from my own project, to which I did, in fact, attach the debugger, I'd understand, but the project to which the pdb file that gets locked belongs hasn't even been run on my machine, let alone debugged. I only built the project.

Comment: Do you need the pdb files when iterating over the release folder or why do you generate them, if you want a release version?
I would say turn it off, then u will not have that weired problem.
Just turn them off for all the projects when in release mode!

Comment: I'm going to try this, the build takes about 30 minutes so I'll report back.

Comment: In VS toolbar set it to Release mode, then every project will be in release mode. Go to Build and at the end of the page click on the Advanced button.
There you can set the debug info to : none, this is only for the release mode, there will be still pdb files generated in debug mode!

Comment: VS2013 does not lock files.  It is the shrink-wrapped malware that programmers voluntarily install on their machine that does this.  It injects itself into processes so it only *looks* like devenv.exe is the evil-doer.  You must make an exclusion for your project directory.  Uninstall it completely if it is Avast.

Comment: I'm not building the project from Visual Studio but am using [BuildManager.Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager.build%28v=vs.121%29.aspx) within my project, so in my globalProperties Dictionary which I pass to the BuildRequestData I did `GlobalProperties.Add("DebugSymbols", "false");`. I'm currently awaiting results but I have a good feeling about it :-).

Comment: Hans Passant, there are many documented cases where Visual Studio does in fact lock files.

[See here for an example, also pertaining to PDB files, and acknowledged as a Visual Studio problem by it's developers](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808471/pdbs-locked-after-debugging-session-in-vs2013). [Another one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811991/visual-studio-locks-pdb-files-and-the-build-fails-with-error-msb3061).

Also, the machine I'm currently working on does not have any "shrink-wrapped malware" installed on it.

Comment: Yes, but I mean the projects in the solutions you get from TFS, they should not contain pdb files in the release folder. Perhaps ti works with thisGlobalProp setting, don't know. Don't know ur build process :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm debugging a project named "AutoReleaseService.exe" which uses Microsoft.Build.Execution.Buildmanager to build (but not run or debug!) a number of other projects, among which CalithaLibrary.

Well, CalithaLibrary looks like a DLL project, which is most certainly being used when you run AutoReleaseService.exe. It is straightforward - when the exe project is run, it uses all of the dll-s which it depends on. Visual Studio (devenv.exe) locks the .pdb files, because they are the link between the source code and the executable when you debug the application, and if you open the executable from outside of Visual Studio - they are not locked, because you do not need them then.

Comment: The application I'm running does not rely on CalithaLibrary.dll. I'm starting to be pretty sure this is a bug in MSBuild

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to become pretty sure there's a bug in MSBuild here somewhere.

Luckily I managed to debug the last part of the application I needed to debug by excluding a few of the builds it was making, so it's now running in Release and does not encounter problems anymore.

Some information on why I think it must be a bug.

My application's workflow was something like this:

- Create a temporary workspace on Team Foundation Server
- GET a number of solutions/projects from TFS to a temporary folder
- BUILD a number of these (configurable through xml but that's beside the point) to a different temporary folder
- Clean up the temporary folder with source code

I tried setting MSBuild Options "DebugType" to none and "DebugSymbols" to false, but for some reason it kept outputting the Program Database files which is why I think there's a bug somewhere.

Whenever I skipped the "Building" step and skipped straight ahead to "Clean up" there were no locks on any files.